# prove without induction that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p=?$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I want to find the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ for $p\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is there an algebraic method to solve this?

If you can also suggest good references for this question, it's good enough for me.

Comment: The statement isn't right. You probably mean that the left-hand side is a polynomial whose leading term is what you've written on the right.

Comment: Since it isn't true, it is hard to prove without induction. In any event, assuming you fixed the question, all you can do is hide the induction, because the left side is defined inductively, and you'd have to apply a theorem that uses induction whatever you do.

Comment: Let us try for $n=2,k=1$, the statement is $3=4/2=2$ ....

Comment: The identity in the title is not true at all. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: Ok, thanks @Masacroso it helped.

Comment: Given that there is no good algebraic formula of this sum when $p$ is a negative integer, I think you are going to have trouble coming up with a formula.

Comment: And consider $p=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\sum_1^n \sqrt{k}$ is in the quadratic field including all square roots of primes less than $n$. Since we don't have a good formula for the number of such primes, it means we probably can't come up with an algebraic expression for that sum.

Comment: In particular, the best you can do is estimates.

Comment: You can apply the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), which gives an exact answer in the case of polynomials.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what is the best formula we do have for the number of such primes? I know we have the prime number theorem with asymptotic expansion; can we have even better formula?

Comment: There are loads of refinements of less and less loveliness that give greater accuracy. But none of them look "algebraic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is known as the Bernoulli polynomial (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).

If $B_{p+1}$ is a polynomial od degree $p$, and ,
$\sum_{k=0}^n k^p= {B_{p+1}(n+1)-B_{p+1}(0)\over p+1}$

Comment: You should add this only works for $p$ integers. (The question is very specific about looking at $p$ rational.)

Comment: Right, for more general function there is a well known formula, the Euler Mac Laurin Formula which give you the asymptotics of such a sum..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula.

Answer (score 2):

$$ p\in \mathbb{Q}\\n\to \infty\\(1^p+2^p+3^p+...+n^p)=\\\frac{n^{p+1}}{n^{p+1}}(1^p+2^p+3^p+...+n^p)=n^{p+1}(\frac{1^p+2^p+3^p+...+n^p}{n^{p+1}})=\\
n^{p+1}(\frac{1}{n}((\frac{1}{n})^p+(\frac{2}{n})^p+(\frac{3}{n})^p+...+(\frac{n}{n})^p))=\\
n^{p+1}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{i}{n})^p\approx n^{p+1}\int_{0}^{1}x^pdx=n^{p+1}\frac{1}{p+1}\\\to 
1^p+2^p+...+n^p \approx \frac{n^{p+1}}{P+1}$$

Comment: If course, $\int_{0}^1 x^p\,dx$ is not always $\frac{1}{p+1}$. This only works for $p>-1$.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compare to the corresponding integral: $\int_{1}^{n} x^p dx$.

Comment: would the downvoter explain pls?